# Doubt in John Langford's "Tutorial on Practical Prediction Theory for Classiﬁcation" paper

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning

I am reading John Langford's paper on practical prediction theory ([link](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/Langford05.pdf)), and I have the following doubt with definition of Binomial Tail inversion.

The paper says that binomial tail inversion is the largest true error such that the probability of having k or more errors is at least $\delta$.

But the expression used in the paper reads "largest true error such that probability of having k or **less** errors is at least $\delta$"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a typo.

In the Definition 2.1 and Definition 2.2, the estimation of $c_D$ is done by empirical summation of $\mathbf{1}(c(x_i) = y_i)$.

Later in the Definition 3.1 it used the following notation : 
$$
... = \Pr_{...} \left( \sum_i Z_i < k \right) = ...
$$
In this notation $Z_i=1$ corresponds to correct decisions or $c(x_i) = y_i$, and $Z_i=0$ corresponds to the mistakes or $c(x_i) \neq y_i$. I suppose that in this binomial representation $Z_i = 1$ (correct decision) corresponds to `heads" (And similarly $Z_i = 0$ (wrong decision) corresponds to`tail").

That said, the right sentence seems to be "... having k or less errors is at least $\delta$"